# Casein form for ActiveRecord::Store hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, store

I have a Rails 4.2 app which uses Casein 5.1 as an admin interface. I've scaffolded the `Page` model with regular fields (`title` and `content`) in the normal way, which works fine, but I can't work out how to add values to a hash `properties` which uses `ActiveRecord::Store`:

```
#page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :properties
end
```

All I've changed in the controller is adding `properties` to the permitted params:

```
#pages_controller.rb
def page_params
  params.require(:page).permit(:title, :content, :properties)
end
```

The form at the moment looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <%= casein_text_field f, f.object, :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <%= casein_text_area f, f.object, :content %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :properties do |ff| %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <%= casein_text_field ff, ff.object, :test_property %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

The `properties` hash is being saved as an empty hash. How can I pass a value so that `properties.test_property` can be changed via the admin?

edit: If someone with enough rep wanted to create a Casein tag, that would be cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model: `store :properties, accessors: [:test_property]`

In the controller: `params.require(:page).permit(:test_property)`

In the page form:
`<%= casein_text_field f, f.object, :test_property %>`

Then use it, e.g. `@page.test_property`

(I found the answer to this ages ago and forgot to update the question)